# crontab and binaries in /usr/local/bin

Tags: bash, environment-variables, crontab

I am working in `Redhat` and have few programs located in folder `/usr/local/bin` I would like to call from `crontab` for `root` user.
I thought that by putting binaries in that folder would be sufficient to call the program directly as in the shell.

Essentially I need to specifiy the folder everytime so the crontab below doesn't work

```
 5 9  * * 1,2,3,4,5 my_bin some_args
```

but I change it into

```
 5 9  * * 1,2,3,4,5 source ~/.bashrc; /usr/local/bin/my_bin some_args
```

Do you know why?

The reason why I sourced `bashrc` was to add some environment libraries, in particular `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as  my binary couldn't find some shared libraries from `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but still: it's helpful to say the error (it was likely sent by e-mail to the root user), and make sure the files are executable (`chmod +x`).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

cron jobs run in a very minimal environment, and since they're executed directly by `crond` without a shell (unless you force one to be created), the regular shell setup never happens. There are two standardish ways to work around this. First, you can define environment variables in your crontab (note that these'll apply to all jobs -- at least, those listed after the definitions):

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

5 9  * * 1,2,3,4,5 my_bin some_args
```

Second, you can edit the script to be less dependent on its environment (e.g. have it define what it's going to need itself), and then use the full path in the crontab entry:

```
5 9  * * 1,2,3,4,5 /usr/local/bin/my_bin some_args
```

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thank you very much. Essentially I am using the second solution but I really like the first one.

Comment: Typically, /usr/bin programs are available. Is there a reason not to link the program you want (ln -s /usr/local/bin/my_bin /usr/bin/my_bin) so it's available that way?

Comment: @juacala I wouldn't mess up your filesystem organization to work around an oddity of cron. The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) says that locally-installed binaries belong in /usr/local/bin, not /usr/bin; using symlinks doesn't technically violate this, but it certainly violates the intent. Plus it adds another thing to go wrong if you don't keep the symlinks up to date (adding/removing them as programs are added/removed). Plus it doesn't handle binaries in /sbin or /usr/sbin...

Comment: I decided to do this: `0 0 * * * /bin/bash -l -c "PATH=\"$PATH:/usr/local/bin\"; <your command here>"`

Comment: Just a side note: `$PATH` only contains `/usr/bin:/bin` in cronjobs on Ubuntu